I need to test a transistor
How do I test this transistor?
It is part of the main control board of a welder that got plugged into 480 V when the welder is a 230 V single phase. I definitely do not want to plug it in and doing so will do no good until I get repairs underway if it's worth repairing.

Bottom of PCB view with apparent connections.


From your other question, you have literally vaporized traces on the board. It is toast. Every component is suspect IMO.

Did it blow a fuse?

Find out how much a replacement board would cost.

IF there are no ICs involved you MAY have a chance. If there are ICs they are quiite likely dead. || If you can tell us as much as possible of the part number we MAY be able to help. The photo is hard to read. Just possibly another there has the same number. || I  consider it LIKELY but NOT certain that it is a SCR or TRIAC of Style 3 here.  || The left hand pin (lower here) is connected to what is probably a ground plane. This matches no std transistor type. Under PCB image here https://i.sstatic.net/oT03Ii2A.jpg

What is the IC partt number shown as "Drive IC part"? || A good quality well lit well focused image of the top of the whole PCB with part numbers readable where intact would help a lot. || This question MAY be able to be reopened with enough detail. || For interest and of possible relevance to repair, where are you located?
